# Copycat in Russian?

Tags: перевод

What it says on the tin: how would you say "copycat" in Russian?

The verb "обезьянничать" (dictionary translation for "copycat") does not quite cut it - it implies making faces or being silly - while "copycat" is more neutral.

Comment: *Обезьянничать* is not as narrow as that; I'd say it's as versatile as the literal English equivalent, "to ape" — if also equally infrequently used.

Comment: I included "обезьянничать" because that's the dictionary translation. Edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Depending on situation подражать or передразнивать can be used.

Comment: In modern detective fiction it is usually a noun (about a person, imitating M. O. of a known serial criminal) meaning "подражатель".

Comment: It's all depends on the context. Can you add sentence by example? And I try to fnid  alternative.

Comment: "Косить" еще. ^_^

Comment: "Повторюшка" is also a widely used word, especially among children.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically a person who is a copycat is "подражатель" or "имитатор"
If it's related to subculture, person is "позёр"

Answer (score 3):

When a was a child we called them: повторюшка, дядя хрюшка